# Office js api - bad request due to _host_info

Tags: office-js

I'm developing Office Add-in using Office JS api. It has to be hosted on SAP Cloud Platform as HTML5 Application.

The problem is that when I run the add-in from desktop version (Excel 2016) I get error *ADD-IN ERROR A problem occured while trying to reach this add-in*. I tracked the request in Fiddler and found the cause - it's the **_host_info** parameter added to the GET request. It has parameters delimited by "**|**". Cloud Platform has problem parsing this url and responds with *400 Bad Request*.

sample from Fiddler:

```
GET /index.html?_host_Info=Excel|Win32|16.01|en-US HTTP/1.1
```

It the add-in is run from the 365 office version, everything is ok - the **_host_info** parameter is not present in request.

Is there any way how to get this working?

1. Can I somehow force the Excel to skip/encode the **_host_info** parameter?
2. Can I convince the SAP Cloud Platform to accept the "**|**" in url query parameter?

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: What is the version and build number of your desktop Excel 2016?

Comment: Sounds like a bug from Microsoft. The _host_Info parameter should be URL encoded and then SCP will accept it.

Comment: @RickKirkham Microsoft Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.7329.1047) 32-bit

Interesting is that MS knows about this and removed the parameter from web version earlier (there is thread on stackoverflow about that)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to skip the _host_info parameter as it is required to download the right JS scripts. The server client uses a different encoding. Some servers can't handle | and this is one of the cases. I don't know of a mitigation at this point. Will get back with any suggestion we may have.

Comment: Is there any progress?

Comment: We updated the docs here: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins. Basically, Office automatically adds a query parameter called _host_info to the URL that is passed to displayDialogAsync. (It is appended after your custom query parameters, if any. It is not appended to any subsequent URLs that the dialog box navigates to).

Comment: For those issues caused by hostinfo appended in auth page, workaround is (1) Open the dialog in your own domain page
(2) In that page, redirect to the auth page. 
In this case, we don't append hostinfo after redirection, and it should resolve the issue.

Comment: This appears to still be an issue, was a better mitigation, workaround found or fix delivered?

Comment: To answer myself, it seems not. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/896
Terrible response there.